# Log value into console that is placed in HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, serial-port, socket.io

I am using node.js to create a server that brings in serial data.  The serial data is successfully showing in the HTML; however, I would like to create a 'var' that can hold the data.  Please can someone help?

Here is my index.html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        // open a connection to the serial server:
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

         // when you get a serialdata event, do this:
        socket.on('serialEvent', function (data) {
            // look for the textDisplay element in the HTML below:
            var element = document.getElementById('IDTag');
            // set the stuff inside the element's HTML tags to
            // whatever the 'value' property of the received data is:
            element.innerHTML = data.value;

            });

  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    And the latest is:
    <div id="IDTag">The RFID Tag ID will show here.</div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my SerialServer.js doc:

```
/*
    serialServer.js
    a node.js app to read serial strings and send them to webSocket clients
    requires:
        * node.js (http://nodejs.org/)
        * express.js (http://expressjs.com/)
        * socket.io (http://socket.io/#how-to-use)
        * serialport.js (https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport)

    based on the core examples for socket.io and serialport.js

    created 21 Aug 2012
    modified 14 Oct 2012
    by Tom Igoe

    Patches and improvements suggested by Steve Klise, Lia Martinez, and Will Jennings

*/


var serialport = require("serialport"),             // include the serialport library
    SerialPort  = serialport.SerialPort,            // make a local instance of serial
    app = require('express')(),                     // start Express framework
    server = require('http').createServer(app),     // start an HTTP server
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);       // filter the server using socket.io

var serialData = {};                                // object to hold what goes out to the client

server.listen(8080);                                // listen for incoming requests on the server

console.log("Listening for new clients on port 8080");

// open the serial port. Change the name to the name of your port, just like in Processing and Arduino:
var myPort = new SerialPort("/dev/tty.usbmodemfa131", { 
    // look for return and newline at the end of each data packet:
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n") 
});

// respond to web GET requests with the index.html page:
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  response.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// listen for new socket.io connections:
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // if there's a socket client, listen for new serial data:  
    myPort.on('data', function (data) {
        // set the value property of scores to the serial string:
        serialData.value = data;
        // for debugging, you should see this in Terminal:
        console.log(data);
        // send a serial event to the web client with the data:
        socket.emit('serialEvent', serialData);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise moving all the javascript to the end of the page, before the closing body tag (instead of the head tag).

Secondly, I find it strange that you run a socket.io server as well as an http server on the same port.

I'm not even sure that is the correct way of running socket.io, I would advise playing around with the official demos instead (they're guaranteed to work).

Comment: Running Socket.io and a HTTP server on the same port is normal and correct, since Socket.io uses Ajax long polling and WebSockets, both of which are perfectly compatible with HTTP. Look at the second demo on the [Socket.io example page](http://socket.io/#how-to-use), "*Using with the Express 3 web framework*".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll have a look into it.

Although, would you be able to help me work out how to put the serial data into a variable so I can also show it in the console log?